# Snowflake credit cost for storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to monitor the credit usage for my snowflake account.
For warehouse I can get the credit info from metering history where I can see which warehouse had how many credits .
However I am not able to get the info for storage, For example I can see there is 12 tables whose size is huge like 100 plus terrabytes. I am getting that info from TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS.
But I need to know how much credits are getting used by those table.

Is there any view or table in information schema which can shows how many credits are getting used for these table.

Comment: You credits is the AVG size/day for the month. Thus if you use total 100tb, 110tb, 120tb,130tb (over weeks to simplify the example math), you pay for 115tb.

Comment: Your credits per TB per month will depend on your contract. You can get that information from your Snowflake account manager. Once you have that, you can calculate the number of credits based on the average number of TB during the month as Simeon describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look at the average daily bytes used in the last days, you can use `stage_storage_usage_history`:

```sql
select *
from table(information_schema.stage_storage_usage_history(dateadd('days',-10,current_date()), current_date()));
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/stage_storage_usage_history.html

If you want to look at the detail from stages and databases:

```sql
select convert_timezone('UTC', usage_date) as usage_date
    ,   database_name as object_name
    ,   'database' as object_type
    ,   max(AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES) as database_bytes
    ,   max(AVERAGE_FAILSAFE_BYTES) as failsafe_bytes
    ,   0 as stage_bytes 
from snowflake.account_usage.database_storage_usage_history 
where usage_date >= date_trunc('day', ('2021-12-01')::timestamp_ntz)  
and usage_date < date_trunc('day', ('2021-12-05')::timestamp_ntz) 
group by 1, 2, 3 

union all select convert_timezone('UTC', usage_date) as usage_date
    ,   'Stages' as object_name
    ,   'stage' as object_type
    ,   0 as database_bytes
    ,   0 as failsafe_bytes
    ,   max(AVERAGE_STAGE_BYTES) as stage_bytes 
from snowflake.account_usage.stage_storage_usage_history 
where usage_date >= date_trunc('day', ('2021-12-01')::timestamp_ntz)  
and usage_date < date_trunc('day', ('2021-12-05')::timestamp_ntz) 
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/database_storage_usage_history.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/stage_storage_usage_history.html

As Greg says in a comment, you can transform these monthly average bytes into credits with a formula that will depend on the specifics of your account contract.